# How To "Image" An EC2 Instance For Training Purposes

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to create some training videos where I install software on a Windows machine.  There might be several scenarios that I have to cover so I want to start with an "out of the box" install of Windows for each video.  Is there a way to do this with AWS EC2 without having to destroy and create a new instance each time?

The perfect situation would be where I could export an image and then reload that image when I start the instance again.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EC2 uses Amazon Machine Images (AMIs) to create a bootable copy of a disk. An AMI can be created from an existing instance. When an AMI is used to **launch** a new instance, the disk will contain an exact copy of the original disk.

This does, however, involve launching a new instance.

If you want your disk to magically reset *without* creating a new instance, then you'll need to find a Windows utility that provides this capability (like [Deep Freeze](https://www.faronics.com/en-uk/products/deep-freeze/enterprise)) since this takes place *inside* the computer and Operating System, which AWS cannot access.